# Where did the flash of purple come from when Ron got splinched in Chapter 13 of the Deathly Hallows?

Tags: harry-potter

> There was a noise in the cubicle behind them; Harry looked around: Yaxley had just appeared.
>
> “LET’S GO!” Harry yelled. He seized Hermione by the hand and Ron by the arm and turned on the spot.
>
> Darkness engulfed them, along with the sensation of compressing hands, but something was wrong... Hermione’s hand seemed to be sliding out of his grip...
>
> He wondered whether he was going to suffocate; he could not breathe or see and the only solid things in the world were Ron’s arm and Hermione’s fingers, which were slowly slipping away... And then he saw the door of number twelve, Grimmauld Place, with its serpent door knocker, but before he could draw breath, there was a scream **and a flash of purple light**. Hermione’s hand was suddenly vicelike upon his hand and everything went dark again.
>
> <sub>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows* - Chapter 13</sub>

Where did the flash of purple come from?

Comment: A spell cast against them, probably; https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Antonin_Dolohov%27s_curse

Comment: From hermione almost certainly, but it's obviously deliberately written to be confusing to reflect harry's state of confusion and the confusing nature of events

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was presumably what Hermione described in the beginning of the next chapter:

> “Harry, I think he can. I — I forced him to let go with a Revulsion Jinx, but I’d already taken him inside the Fidelius Charm’s protection. Since Dumbledore died, we’re Secret-Keepers, so I’ve given him the secret, haven’t I?”